# iterating over dictionaries for getting all elements using single loop

Tags: python, dictionary

Consider a dictionary like this

```
a_dict = {"a":1,"b":3,"c":4}
b_dict = {"d":44,"e":23}
for (k,v),(k1,v1) in zip(a_dict.items(),b_dict.items()):
    print(k,v);
    print(k1,v1);
```

Using this code I got two elements from each dictionary. Like:

```
b 3  
e 23  
c 4  
d 44
```

Here I didn't get:

```
a 1
```

from dictionary `a_dict`.
But I want all elements from each dictionary using a single loop that is three elements from `a_dict` and two elements from `b_dict`. Is there any easy way to do that task?

Comment: Please post the desired output. Your description thereof is pretty vague

Comment: You are zipping two sets of different length!!

Comment: You probably want to use [`itertools.izip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) (or `zip_longest` if you're using Python 3)

Comment: You also seem to want to use `zip`, which is intended and mainly used for ordered iterables, for a `dict`, which is very not ordered. I sense an XY problem. Please explain WHY you want to do this

Comment: You are not iterating over dictionaries, but over lists (`items()`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `zip()` stops when it reaches the end of the smaller sequence. If you would prefer something different you can use `itertools.zip_longest()`

```
from itertools import zip_longest
a_dict = {"a":1,"b":3,"c":4}
b_dict = {"d":44,"e":23}
for a_pair,b_pair in zip_longest(a_dict.items(),b_dict.items()):
    if a_pair:
        print(a_pair[0],a_pair[1])
    if b_pair:
        print(b_pair[0],b_pair[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Chaining both items gives you all key-value pairs in the loop:

```
from itertools import chain

a_dict = {"a":1,"b":3,"c":4}
b_dict = {"d":44,"e":23}

for k, v in chain(a_dict.items(),b_dict.items()):
    print(k, v)
```

Output:

```
c 4
a 1
b 3
e 23
d 44
```

Answer (score -2):

The low-tech way is to iterate through your dictionaries, handling each one in turn:

```
a_dict = {"a":1,"b":3,"c":4}
b_dict = {"d":44,"e":23}
for c in (a_dict, b_dict):
    for (k,v) in (c.iteritems()):
        print(k,v);
```

output:

```
('a', 1)
('c', 4)
('b', 3)
('e', 23)
('d', 44)
```

Comment: If this is what is desired, you can use `itertools.chain` to avoid the nesting: `for k, v in chain(a_dict.items(), b_dict.items()):`